# How to downsize code that uses DHT11 for AVR (Attiny45)

Tags: arduino, sensors, attiny, code-size

I'm trying to build a small hygrometer based on the DHT11 and I'm having a bit of an "issue" with the code size. I want to run it on an Attiny45 and it's a wee bit too big (352 bytes too big to be exact). I am aware that I could just use an Attiny85 and have space to spare or don't use a bootloader and barely fit it in (94%) but I kind of want to make my life harder than it needs to be and figure out how to reduce size since it'll probably come in handy in the future. Treat it as a learning experience if you will.

What it's supposed to do:

- Read DHT11 input
- Display results on 2 two-digit 7-segment displays (so I guess 4 7-segments in total)
- Go to sleep most of the time to preserve battery
- Wake up every 8 seconds to update sensor values (without turning on the display)
- Wake up on a button press to display the values for humidity and temperature

Side note: 7-segments are adressed via two 74HC595s of which I am using 7 outputs each for the displays and 1 each for a transistor that connects the display in question to GND. There's a schematic at the bottom if you're interested.

As pointed out, my main issue is code size so if anyone has any tips on how to reduce that (or any other tips how to improve the code) please let me know.

I hope I'm asking the question properly, if not please let me know.

---

**Compiler output:**

```
Sketch uses 3872 bytes (110%) of program storage space. Maximum is 3520 bytes.text section exceeds available space in board

Global variables use 107 bytes (41%) of dynamic memory, leaving 149 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 256 bytes.
Sketch too big; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on reducing it.
Error compiling for board ATtiny45/85 (Optiboot).
```

---

**Code:**

```cpp
/*
Humidity/Temperature sensor setup with DHT-11
Two digits for humidity
Two digits for temperature
Button to wake up from sleep
NPNs activated via 8th bit in 74HC595s, always alternating

Author:   ElectroBadger
Date:     2021-11-02
Version:  1.0
*/

/*
Reduce power consumption:
- Run at 1 MHz internal clock
- Turn off ADC
- Use SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN
*/

#include "DHT.h" //DHT-11 sensor
#include <avr/sleep.h> // Sleep Modes
#include <avr/power.h> // Power management
#include <avr/wdt.h> //Doggy stuff

//define attiny pins
#define INT_PIN PB4
#define DATA PB1
#define SENSOR PB3
#define LATCH PB2
#define CLK PB0

//define other stuff
#define SENSOR_TYPE DHT11
#define LED_DELAY 50

//changing variables
short ones_data; //16-bits for display of ones
short tens_data; //16-bits for display of tens
byte sevSeg, measurements; //7-segment bit pattern / wait time between LEDs [ms] / # of measurements taken
bool firstPair, btnPress; //tracks which pair of 7-segments is on; tracks button presses
uint32_t oldMillis, sleepTimer; //tracks the last acquisition time and wakeup time

//Initialize sensor
DHT dht(SENSOR, SENSOR_TYPE);

//Shifts 16 bits out MSB first, on the rising edge of the clock.
void shiftOut(int dataPin, int clockPin, short toBeSent){
  int i=0;
  int pinState = 0;
  
  //Clear everything out just in case
  digitalWrite(dataPin, 0);
  digitalWrite(clockPin, 0);

  //Loop through bits in the data bytes, COUNTING DOWN in the for loop so that
  //0b00000000 00000001 or "1" will go through such that it will be pin Q0 that lights.
  for(i=0; i<=15; i++){
    digitalWrite(clockPin, 0);
    //if the value passed to myDataOut AND a bitmask result
    //is true then set pinState to 1
    if(toBeSent & (1<<i)){
      pinState = 1;
    }
    else{
      pinState = 0;
    }
    
    digitalWrite(dataPin, pinState); //Sets the pin to HIGH or LOW depending on pinState
    digitalWrite(clockPin, 1); //Shifts bits on upstroke of clock pin
    digitalWrite(dataPin, 0); //Zero the data pin after shift to prevent bleed through
  }
  digitalWrite(clockPin, 0); //Stop shifting
}

//Converts an int <10 to a bit pattern for 7-segment displays
short toSegments(int value){
  byte pattern = 0b00000000; //create empty pattern

  //Using a switch...case (3878 bytes) if...else if...else uses 3946 bytes
  switch(value){
    case 0:
      pattern = 0b01111110;
      break;
    case 1:
      pattern = 0b00110000;
      break;
    case 2:
      pattern = 0b01101101;
      break;
    case 3:
      pattern = 0b01111001;
      break;
    case 4:
      pattern = 0b00110011;
      break;
    case 5:
      pattern = 0b01011011;
      break;
    case 6:
      pattern = 0b01011111;
      break;
    case 7:
      pattern = 0b01110000;
      break;
    case 8:
      pattern = 0b01111111;
      break;
    case 9:
      pattern = 0b01111011;
      break;
    default:
      pattern = 0b00000000;
      break;
  }

  return pattern;
}

void goToSleep(){
  //Turn off 7-segments and NPNs
  digitalWrite(LATCH, 0);
  shiftOut(DATA, CLK, 0b0000000000000000); 
  digitalWrite(LATCH, 1);
  //Set deep sleep mode
  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  ADCSRA = 0; // turn off ADC
  power_all_disable (); // power off ADC, Timer 0 and 1, serial interface
  cli(); // timed sequence coming up, so disable interrupts
  btnPress = false;
  measurements = 0;
  resetWatchdog (); // get watchdog ready
  sleep_enable (); // ready to sleep
  sei(); // interrupts are required now
  sleep_cpu (); // sleep                
  sleep_disable (); // precaution
  power_all_enable (); // power everything back on
}
        
ISR(PCINT_VECTOR){
  btnPress = true;
  sleepTimer = millis();
}

// watchdog interrupt
ISR(WDT_vect){
  wdt_disable(); //disable watchdog
}

void resetWatchdog(){
  MCUSR = 0; //clear various "reset" flags    
  WDTCR = bit (WDCE) | bit (WDE) | bit (WDIF); //allow changes, disable reset, clear existing interrupt
  //set interrupt mode and an interval (WDE must be changed from 1 to 0 here)
  WDTCR = bit (WDIE) | bit (WDP3) | bit (WDP0); //set WDIE, and 8 seconds delay
  wdt_reset(); //pat the dog
  }
 
void setup(){
  resetWatchdog(); // do this first in case WDT fires
  cli(); //Disable interrupts during setup
  
  pinMode(INT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); //Set interrupt pin as input w/ internal pullup
  pinMode(DATA, OUTPUT); //Set serial data as output
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT); //Set shift register clock as output
  pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT); //Set output register (latch) clock as output
  
  // Interrupts
  PCMSK = bit(INT_PIN); //Enable interrupt handler (ISR)
  GIFR  |= bit(PCIF); // clear any outstanding interrupts
  GIMSK |= bit(PCIE); //Enable PCINT interrupt in the general interrupt mask

  //default conditions
  /*  bit 0-6: ones digits
  bit 7: NPN for units digits
  bit 8-14: ones digits
  bit 15: NPN for tens digits
  */
  ones_data = 0b0000000000000000;
  tens_data = 0b0000000000000000;
  measurements = 0;
  firstPair = true;
  btnPress = false;
  oldMillis = 0;
  sleepTimer = 0;
  
  //Start sensor
  dht.begin();
  delay(1000); //wait 1s for sensor to stabilize
        
  sei(); //Enable interrupts after setup
}

void loop(){ 
  if((millis()-oldMillis) > 1000){
    //Slow sensor, so readings may be up to 2 seconds old
    byte hum = dht.readHumidity(); //Read humidity
    byte temp = dht.readTemperature(); //Read temperatuer in °C
    
    //update tens bit string
    tens_data = 0b0000000000000000; //reset to all 0s
    sevSeg = toSegments(hum/10); //convert tens of humidity to 7-segment logic
    tens_data |= sevSeg; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
    tens_data = tens_data << 8; //shift by 8 so it's almost in the right place (see below)
    sevSeg = toSegments(temp/10); //convert tens of temperature to 7-segment logic
    tens_data |= sevSeg; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
    tens_data = tens_data << 1; //shift by 1 so everything is in the right place
    tens_data |= 0b0000000100000000; //set NPN for tens pair to active and ones NPN to inactive 
    
    //update ones bit string
    ones_data = 0b0000000000000000; //reset to all 0s
    sevSeg = toSegments(hum%10); //convert ones of humidity to 7-segment logic
    ones_data |= sevSeg; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
    ones_data = ones_data << 8; //shift by 8 so it's almost in the right place (see below)
    sevSeg = toSegments(temp%10); //convert ones of temperature to 7-segment logic
    ones_data |= sevSeg; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
    ones_data = ones_data << 1; //shift by 1 so everything is in the right place
    ones_data |= 0b0000000000000001; //set NPN for ones pair to active and tens NPN to inactive 
    
    oldMillis = millis(); //I don't much care about the few ms lost
  }             //during data acquisition
  
  if(btnPress){
    //shift out the next batch of data to the display
    digitalWrite(LATCH, 0); //Set latch pin LOW so nothing gets shifted out
    if(firstPair){
      shiftOut(DATA, CLK, tens_data); //Shift out LED states for 7-segments of tens
      firstPair = false;
    }
    else{
      shiftOut(DATA, CLK, ones_data); //Shift out LED states for 7-segments of ones
      firstPair = true;
    }
    digitalWrite(LATCH, 1); //sent everything out in parallel
    delay(LED_DELAY); //wait for some time until switching to the other displays
    
    if((millis()-sleepTimer) > 6000){ //Sleep after 6s display time
      goToSleep();
    }
  }
  else{
    if(measurements > 5){
      goToSleep();
    }
  }
}
```

---

[DHT11 hygrometer schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wmf4.png)

Comment: The DHT library uses floats which is going to be expensive in time and code size on a small AVR. And since you only use the integer part anyway, you can do that for probably much less cost. (Try removing the DHT part from your code and look at the code size left.) Also replace your big switch with an array lookup, that should save a couple bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Surprisingly the switch to an array lookup made only a 2 byte difference, but boy did ditching the library help. Can I somehow upvote your comment or leave reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so thanks to the input of Mat I tried substituting the DHT11 library with something more sleek, which took me a while to get up and running. I ended up using [this](https://www.engineersgarage.com/articles-arduino-dht11-humidity-temperature-sensor-interfacing/) as a base, edited around a bit and commented heavily for my benefit.
I added my updated code below for anyone interested (thanks for pointing out the correct highlighting issue), there's also a [github](https://github.com/rustyRaccoon/Hygrometer.git) with the rest of the design files.

Seems the library is really heavy, as the compiler output shows:

**Compiler output:**

```
Sketch uses 2354 bytes (66%) of program storage space. Maximum is 3520 bytes.
Global variables use 104 bytes (40%) of dynamic memory, leaving 152 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 256 bytes.
```

**Code:**

```cpp
/*
  Humidity/Temperature sensor setup with DHT-11
  Two digits for humidity
  Two digits for temperature
  Button to wake up from sleep
  NPNs activated via 8th bit in 74HC595s, always alternating

  Author:   ElectroBadger
  Date:     2021-11-09
  Version:  2.0
*/

/*
  Reduce power consumption:
  - Run at 1 MHz internal clock
  - Turn off ADC
  - Use SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN
*/

//#include "DHT.h"      // DHT-11 sensor
#include <avr/sleep.h>  // Sleep Modes
#include <avr/power.h>  // Power management
#include <avr/wdt.h>    // Doggy stuff

// define attiny pins
#define INT_PIN PB4
#define DATA PB1
#define SENSOR PB3
#define LATCH PB2
#define CLK PB0

// define other stuff
//#define SENSOR_TYPE DHT11
#define LED_DELAY 50

//fixed variables
//array lookup for number display; ascending order: 0, 1, 2, ...
const byte numLookup[] = {
  0b01111110, //0
  0b00110000, //1
  0b01101101, //2
  0b01111001, //3
  0b00110011, //4
  0b01011011, //5
  0b01011111, //6
  0b01110000, //7
  0b01111111, //8
  0b01111011  //9
}; 

// changing variables
short ones_data;                // 16-bits for display of ones
short tens_data;                // 16-bits for display of tens
byte sevSeg, measurements;      // 7-segment bit pattern / wait time between LEDs [ms] / # of measurements taken
bool firstPair, btnPress;       // tracks which pair of 7-segments is on; tracks button presses
uint32_t oldMillis, sleepTimer; // tracks the last acquisition time and wakeup time
byte humI, humD, tempI, tempD;  // values of humidity and temperature (we're only gonna need integral parts but I need all for the checksum)

// Initialize sensor
//DHT dht(SENSOR, SENSOR_TYPE);

// Shifts 16 bits out MSB first, on the rising edge of the clock.
void shiftOut(int dataPin, int clockPin, short toBeSent) {
  int i = 0;
  int pinState = 0;

  // Clear everything out just in case
  digitalWrite(dataPin, 0);
  digitalWrite(clockPin, 0);

  // Loop through bits in the data bytes
  for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clockPin, 0);
    // if the value AND a bitmask result is true then set pinState to 1
    if (toBeSent & (1 << i)) {
      pinState = 1;
    }
    else {
      pinState = 0;
    }

    digitalWrite(dataPin, pinState);  // sets the pin to HIGH or LOW depending on pinState
    digitalWrite(clockPin, 1);        // shifts bits on upstroke of clock pin
    digitalWrite(dataPin, 0);         // zero the data pin after shift to prevent bleed through
  }
  digitalWrite(clockPin, 0);          // Stop shifting
}

void start_signal(byte SENSOR_PIN) {
  pinMode(SENSOR_PIN, OUTPUT);        // set pin as output
  digitalWrite(SENSOR_PIN, LOW);      // set pin LOW
  delay(18);                          // wait 18 ms
  digitalWrite(SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);     // set pin HIGH
  pinMode(SENSOR_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);  // set pin as input and pull to VCC (10k)
}

boolean read_dht11(byte SENSOR_PIN) {
  uint16_t rawHumidity = 0;
  uint16_t rawTemperature = 0;
  uint8_t checkSum = 0;
  uint16_t data = 0;

  unsigned long startTime;

  for (int8_t i = -3; i < 80; i++) {  // loop 80 iterations, representing 40 bits * 2 (HIGH + LOW)
    byte high_time;                   // stores the HIGH time of the signal
    startTime = micros();             // stores the time the data transfer started

    // sensor should pull line LOW and keep for 80µs (while SENSOR_PIN == HIGH)
    // then pull HIGH and keep for 80µs (while SENSOR_PIN == LOW)
    // then pull LOW again, aka send data (while SENSOR_PIN == HIGH)
    do {                                                  // waits for sensor to respond
      high_time = (unsigned long)(micros() - startTime);  // update HIGH time
      if (high_time > 90) {                               // times out after 90 microseconds
        Serial.println("ERROR_TIMEOUT");
        return;
      }
    }
    while (digitalRead(SENSOR_PIN) == (i & 1) ? HIGH : LOW);

    // actual data starts at iteration 0
    if (i >= 0 && (i & 1)) {  // if counter is odd, do this (only counts t_on time and ignores t_off)
      data <<= 1;             // left shift data stream by 1 since we are at a the next bit

      // TON of bit 0 is maximum 30µs and of bit 1 is at least 68µs
      if (high_time > 30) {
        data |= 1; // we got a one
      }
    }

    switch ( i ) {
      case 31:                  // bit 0-16 is humidity
        rawHumidity = data;
        break;
      case 63:                  // bit 17-32 is temperature
        rawTemperature = data;
      case 79:                  // bit 33-40 is checksum
        checkSum = data;
        data = 0;
        break;
    }
  }

  // Humidity
  humI = rawHumidity >> 8;
  rawHumidity = rawHumidity << 8;
  humD = rawHumidity >> 8;

  // Temperature
  tempI = rawTemperature >> 8;
  rawTemperature = rawTemperature << 8;
  tempD = rawTemperature >> 8;

  if ((byte)checkSum == (byte)(tempI + tempD + humI + humD)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void goToSleep() {
  // Turn off 7-segments and NPNs
  digitalWrite(LATCH, 0);
  shiftOut(DATA, CLK, 0b0000000000000000);
  digitalWrite(LATCH, 1);
  
  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); // Set deep sleep mode
  ADCSRA = 0;                           // turn off ADC
  power_all_disable ();                 // power off ADC, Timer 0 and 1, serial interface
  cli();                                // timed sequence coming up, so disable interrupts
  btnPress = false;                     // reset button flag
  measurements = 0;                     // reset measurement counter
  resetWatchdog ();                     // get watchdog ready
  sleep_enable ();                      // ready to sleep
  sei();                                // interrupts are required now
  sleep_cpu ();                         // sleep
  sleep_disable ();                     // precaution
  power_all_enable ();                  // power everything back on
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
  btnPress = true;
  sleepTimer = millis();
}

// watchdog interrupt
ISR(WDT_vect) {
  wdt_disable(); // disable watchdog
}

void resetWatchdog() {
  MCUSR = 0;                                    //clear various "reset" flags
  WDTCR = bit (WDCE) | bit (WDE) | bit (WDIF);  //allow changes, disable reset, clear existing interrupt
  WDTCR = bit (WDIE) | bit (WDP3) | bit (WDP0); //set WDIE, and 8 seconds delay
  wdt_reset();
}

void setup() {
  resetWatchdog(); // do this first in case WDT fires
  cli(); // disable interrupts during setup

  pinMode(INT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // set interrupt pin as input w/ internal pullup
  pinMode(DATA, OUTPUT);          //set serial data as output
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);           //set shift register clock as output
  pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT);         //set output register (latch) clock as output
  pinMode(SENSOR, INPUT);         //set DHT11 pin as input

  // Interrupts
  PCMSK = bit(INT_PIN);   // enable interrupt handler (ISR)
  GIFR  |= bit(PCIF);     // clear any outstanding interrupts
  GIMSK |= bit(PCIE);     // enable PCINT interrupt in the general interrupt mask

  //default conditions
  /*  bit 0-6: ones digits
    bit 7: NPN for units digits
    bit 8-14: ones digits
    bit 15: NPN for tens digits
  */
  ones_data = 0b0000000000000000;
  tens_data = 0b0000000000000000;
  measurements = 0;
  firstPair = true;
  btnPress = false;
  oldMillis = 0;
  sleepTimer = 0;
  humI = 0;
  humD = 0;
  tempI = 0;
  tempD = 0;
  
  // Start sensor
  //dht.begin();

  sei(); // enable interrupts after setup
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - oldMillis) > 1000) {
    // slow sensor, so readings may be up to 2 seconds old
    //byte hum = dht.readHumidity(); //Read humidity
    //byte temp = dht.readTemperature(); //Read temperatuer in °C
    delay(2000); // wait for DHT11 to start up
    start_signal(SENSOR); // send start sequence

    if(read_dht11(SENSOR)){
      // update tens bit string
      tens_data = 0b0000000000000000;     // reset to all 0s
      tens_data |= numLookup[humI / 10];  // bitwise OR the result with the output short
      tens_data = tens_data << 8;         // shift by 8 so it's almost in the right place (see below)
      tens_data |= numLookup[tempI / 10]; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
      tens_data = tens_data << 1;         // shift by 1 so everything is in the right place
      tens_data |= 0b0000000100000000;    // set NPN for tens pair to active and ones NPN to inactive
  
      // update ones bit string
      ones_data = 0b0000000000000000;     // reset to all 0s
      ones_data |= numLookup[humI % 10];  // bitwise OR the result with the output short
      ones_data = ones_data << 8;         // shift by 8 so it's almost in the right place (see below)
      ones_data |= numLookup[tempI % 10]; // bitwise OR the result with the output short
      ones_data = ones_data << 1;         // shift by 1 so everything is in the right place
      ones_data |= 0b0000000000000001;    // set NPN for ones pair to active and tens NPN to inactive
    }
    else{
      tens_data = 0b1001111110011100;
      ones_data = 0b0000101000001011;
    }
    oldMillis = millis(); // I don't much care about the few ms lost during data acquisition
  }

  if (btnPress) {
    // shift out the next batch of data to the display
    digitalWrite(LATCH, 0); // Set latch pin LOW so nothing gets shifted out
    
    if (firstPair) {
      shiftOut(DATA, CLK, tens_data); // shift out LED states for 7-segments of tens
      firstPair = false;              // reset first digit flag
    }
    else {
      shiftOut(DATA, CLK, ones_data); //Shift out LED states for 7-segments of ones
      firstPair = true;               //set first digit flag
    }
    
    digitalWrite(LATCH, 1); //sent everything out in parallel
    delay(LED_DELAY);       //wait for some time until switching to the other displays

    if ((millis() - sleepTimer) > 6000) { //Sleep after 6s display time
      goToSleep();
    }
  }
  else {
    if (measurements > 3) {
      goToSleep();
    }
  }
}
```